# Angular2 basic GET Request failing (Likely TS Compile issue?)

Tags: angular, webpack, angular-cli

I have kind of 3 issues running in tandem. I'm trying to understand more about Services/Components so I wanted to make a very basic GET Request.

My `steam.service.ts`:

```
    import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
    import { Http, Response, RequestOptions  } from '@angular/http';
    import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Rx';

    import { Steam } from './steam'

    @Injectable()
    export class SteamService {
        private steamUrl = "http://api.steampowered.com/IPlayerService/GetRecentlyPlayedGames/v0001/?key={redacted}&steamids={redacted2}";

      constructor(
          private http: Http
      ) {}

      getGames(): Observable<Game[]> {
         return this.http.get(this.steamUrl)
                    .map(response => response.json())
                    .catch(this.handleError);
      }

        private handleError (error: Response | any) {
           let errMsg: string;
            if (error instanceof Response) {
              const body = error.json() || '';
              const err = body.error || JSON.stringify(body);
              errMsg = `${error.status} - ${error.statusText || ''} ${err}`;
            } else {
              errMsg = error.message ? error.message : error.toString();
            }
            console.error(errMsg);
            return Observable.throw(errMsg);
        }
    }
```

My `steam.component.ts`

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Rx';

import { Steam } from './steam'
import { SteamService } from './steam.service'

@Component({
    moduleId: module.id,
    selector: 'steam',
    templateUrl:'steam.component.html',
    providers: [ SteamService ]
})
export class SteamComponent implements OnInit {
    games: Game[];
    errorMessage: string;
    mode = "Observable";

  constructor(
      private steamService: SteamService
   ) {}

   getGames() {
       this.steamService.getGames()
           .subscribe(
               games => this.games = games,
               error => this.errorMessage = <any>error
           );
   }

}
```

My `steam.ts` file

```
export interface Game {
    appid: string,
    name: string,
    playtime_2weeks: number,
    playtime_forever: number,
    img_icon_url: string,
    img_logo_url: string
}
```

This code base is heavily reflected off three other components I have that work perfectly. I originally was exporting 'Game' as a component and believed that was part of my issue. I got the error to -temporarily- go away when I changed it to interface.

One issue is SOMETIMES on refresh, or compile. It read

```
ERROR in ~app/steamGames/steam"' has no exported member 'Steam'.)
/home/ubuntu/workspace/freelancedemo/src/app/steamGames/steam.component.ts (13,14): Class 'SteamComponent' incorrectly implements interface 'OnInit'.
  Property 'ngOnInit' is missing in type 'SteamComponent'.)
~/src/app/steamGames/steam.component.ts (14,12): Cannot find name 'Game'.)

ERROR in ~steamGames/steam"' has no exported member 'Steam'.)
~/steam.service.ts (15,26): Cannot find name 'Game'.)
```

It seems to me like this issue might be caused by my interface being named 'Game'? Changing interface to `Steam` will make this error stop, but again this will randomly show up on saves/compiles to no avail.

My real issue is that the API call is never being made - I've watched the Network tab, checked the HTML, and no results.
`app.module.ts`
    import { SteamComponent } from './steamGames/steam.component';
    import { SteamService } from './steamGames/steam.service';

```
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';

    @NgModule({
        imports: [
            ...
        ],
        declarations: [
            ...
            SteamComponent
        ],
        providers:[
            ...
            SteamService
```

I am including it and it's in my Routes.

The one thing I am noticing is that Webpack (I'm using Ang2CLI specifically) isn't mapping the TS -> JS. I am not sure how to force this to happen but I naturally assume that is my primary culprit, so how do you force it to compile properly?

Edit: Forced AngCLI to make the component and still isn't mapping:

`steam.component.js AFTER AngCLI Compiled`

```
"use strict";
Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
var module_1 = require();
if (viewEncapsulation) {
     %  > , ViewEncapsulation <  % ;
}
 %  >  % ;
if (changeDetection) {
     %  > , ChangeDetectionStrategy <  % ;
}
 %  > ;
from;
'@angular/core';
if (inlineTemplate) {
     %  >
        template;
    "\n    <p>\n      steam Works!\n    </p>\n  ",  % ;
}
else {
     %  >
        templateUrl;
    './steam.component.html',  % ;
}
if (inlineStyle) {
     %  >
        styles;
    [] <  % ;
}
else {
     %  >
        styleUrls;
    ['./steam.component.scss'] <  % ;
}
 %  >  % ;
if (viewEncapsulation) {
     %  > ,
        encapsulation;
    ViewEncapsulation. < ;
    viewEncapsulation %  >  % ;
}
if (changeDetection) {
     %  > ,
        changeDetection;
    ChangeDetectionStrategy. < ;
    changeDetection %  >  % ;
}
 %  >
;
var default_1 = (function () {
    function default_1() {
    }
    return default_1;
}());
 %  > module_1.Component;
implements;
module_1.OnInit;
{
    constructor();
    { }
    ngOnInit();
    {
    }
}
//# sourceMappingURL=__name__.component.js.map
```

Comment: Can you add `steam.component.ts` also?

Comment: @Smit Sorry, it was up there but formatting had them combined. Fixed.

Answer (score 1):

You have 2 issues.

In your `SteamComponent`, you define a `getGames()` method, but you don't call it from anywhere.

Secondly, your `SteamComponent` implements OnInit, but that interface requires you to have an `ngOnInit` method on your class. Your SteamComponent doesn't have that method defined.

`ngOnInit` is the method that gets called when a component is created by Angular, so this is where you want to put your call to your `getGames()` method.

Comment: I actually realized this shortly after I kept crawling through. the `ngOnInit` resolved both issues (by calling `getGames()`. Thanks for the detailed reply.

Still no clue why I couldn't use `Game` as the reference of the items.

Comment: @DNorthrup, i think your `Game` issue is because you didn't import the symbol into your javascript module   i.e. you're missing the import {Game} from './whatever file' at the top of the file

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve it, I was actually facing multiple issues.

A) Compilation Issue:
I followed the Rails-esque generator tools of Ang-CLI [here](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli#generating-components-directives-pipes-and-services). This generated 'templates' which I over-wrote. However, I still had compilation issues due to director. I had to go into `file.type.js.map` and edit `,"sourceRoot":"",` to properly reflect it's location.

Once it was compiled my issue was resolved

B) `NgOnInit Warning` - While this warning was also temperamental in when it would spawn it was correct - I never used it, only implemented it. Adding

```
ngOnInit() {
    let timer = Observable.timer(0, 5000);
    timer.subscribe(() => this.getGames());
}
```

Resolved my issue

C) I was not able to proper fix the 'Game' error. This error still only showed up sometimes on reload.
I finally renamed my interface, declaration, and every reference of `Game`, or the Observable `Game` to `Steam` and it resolved my issue.

Turns out joke was on me anyway - Steam follows CORS so Angular alone can't fulfill the call.

Comment: What does Steam following CORS have to do with Angular?  I use Angular on CORS-enabled sites without issue